# What provides curses headers named curses.h?

Tags: command-line, c

I need a few header file namely **curses.h** for text based programming
Please tell me how to install these header files.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can install **libncurses5-dev** package via Software Center or:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Also, you can install the package [by clicking here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libncurses5-dev).

When you need a file or package and can't find it you can use some tools.

**1. apt-file**

First, install apt-file and update it.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
```

You can search with apt-file needed files or packages.

```
apt-file search curses.h
```

**2. Use packages.ubuntu.com**

Go to [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=curses.h&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all).

On right top, select *package contents* if your are searching a file included with a package. If you need a package directly, just search it with its name choosing *package names*.

Comment: can you tell me what libncurses package contains?

Comment: please tell me how to get gtk.h

Comment: @sharik, I edited my answer. Finding packages could be tricky, since when you search those files you can get lots of package names. You must know what you are looking for. Probably you need **libgtk2.0-dev** or **libgtk-3-dev** now. But, since you are using 11.10 first choose **libgtk-3-dev** one. If you have more questions, just edit your question to widen it. Do not ask one by one in your comments.

Comment: Holy crap I can't believe I have never heard of apt-file after using it for all these years.  Thanks for the tip, awesome!

Answer (score 9):

### Find package from file

**Edit:** This only works for an installed package, so is not able to answer the question. Better is heartmagic's answer

To find out what package a file is part of, you can use

```
dpkg -S <file name>
```

For example, `dpkg -S curses.h` gives me this output:

```
libncurses5-dev: /usr/include/ncurses.h
libncurses5-dev: /usr/include/curses.h
```

---

### Find files in package

**Edit:** You need to have the package installed for this to work.

To get the list of files provided by a package, use

```
 dpkg -L <package name>
```

For example `dpkg -L libncurses5-dev` gives me the following output

```
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/curses.h
/usr/include/cursesapp.h
/usr/include/cursesf.h
/usr/include/cursesm.h
/usr/include/cursesp.h
/usr/include/cursesw.h
/usr/include/cursslk.h
/usr/include/eti.h
/usr/include/etip.h
/usr/include/form.h
/usr/include/menu.h
/usr/include/nc_tparm.h
/usr/include/ncurses_dll.h
/usr/include/panel.h
/usr/include/term.h
/usr/include/term_entry.h
/usr/include/termcap.h
/usr/include/tic.h
/usr/include/unctrl.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libform.a
/usr/lib/libmenu.a
/usr/lib/libncurses++.a
/usr/lib/libncurses.a
/usr/lib/libpanel.a
/usr/lib/libtic.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5-dev
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libncurses5-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/include/ncurses.h
/usr/lib/libncurses.so
/usr/lib/libtic.so
/usr/lib/libform.so
/usr/lib/libmenu.so
/usr/lib/libpanel.so
/usr/lib/libcurses.a
/usr/lib/libtermcap.a
/usr/lib/libtermcap.so
/usr/lib/libcurses.so
```

This includes directories as well.

---

### Find ONLY files (not directories) in package

To get just the files the package contains:

```
dpkg -L libncurses5-dev | while read file; do if [[ -f $file ]]; then echo ${file}; fi; done
```

(Description: Get the provided files, and for each one, only print it if it is a file.)

---

### More information

You might find [this table](http://wiki.openvz.org/Package_managers) useful. Just look at the first column (action) and third column (deb) to get a good overview of what you can do. (unless you are curious of course, then look at the other columns.)

Comment: This is a good info. But there is a small problem for this question. Since libncurses5-dev package is not installed and there is no curses.h on his system, he can't use to find the real package what provides this. But, besides that this is a good info.

Comment: @heartsmagic Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I have investigated Contents-i386,etc. (like in http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/archive/dists/oneiric/ ) and thought that it would use that, but actually it does not.